# change gaps in numpy array according to gap size

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, sequence

I need to filter out short nonzero series, that lies between zeros. For example, this array:

```
t = np.array([1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 8, 3, 0, 8, 2, 4, 7, 0,0,4,1])
```

should become:

```
array([1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 2, 4, 7, 0, 0, 4, 1])
```

I found the first indices of non zero sequanceses, and counted num of non zeros between them. I wrote the following, It works, but look awful. I tried staf but got an errors.
How to rewrite it pythonicly ?

```
minseq = 4  # length of minimal non zero seq
p = np.where(fhr>0, 1, 0).astype(int)
s = np.array([1]+ list(np.diff(p)))
sind = np.where(s==1)[0][1:]
print(sind)
    
for i in range(len(sind) - 1):
    s1 = sind[i]
    e1 = sind[i+1]
    
    subfhr = np.where(fhr[s1:e1] > 0, 1, 0).sum()
    
    if (subfhr < minseq):
        
        print(s1, e1, subfhr)
        fhr[s1:e1] = 0
```

out:

```
[ 5  9 15]
5 9 3
array([1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 2, 4, 7, 0, 0, 4, 1])
```

Comment: Just curious, why the `8 2 4 7` series is not turned to zeros?

Comment: @QuangHoang Must be a window parameter, as it removes `1, 8, 3`, but not `8 2 4 7`.

Comment: @QuangHoang 8,2,4,7 length is 4, 1,8,3 length is 3. I will correct the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use image-processing based [`binary_closing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_closing.html) -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_closing

def remove_small_nnz(a, W):
    K = np.ones(W, dtype=int)
    m = a==0
    p = binary_closing(m,K)
    a[~m & p] = 0
    return a
```

Sample run -

```
In [97]: a
Out[97]: array([1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 8, 3, 0, 8, 2, 4, 7, 0, 0, 4, 1])

In [98]: remove_small_nnz(a, W=3)
Out[98]: array([1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 8, 3, 0, 8, 2, 4, 7, 0, 0, 4, 1])

In [99]: remove_small_nnz(a, W=4)
Out[99]: array([1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 2, 4, 7, 0, 0, 4, 1])

In [100]: remove_small_nnz(a, W=5)
Out[100]: array([1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only looking for nonzeros, you can cast the array to boolean, and look for spots where there is a sequence of however many Trues in a row as you're looking for.

```
import numpy as np

def orig(fhr, minseq):
    p = np.where(fhr>0, 1, 0).astype(int)
    s = np.array([1]+ list(np.diff(p)))
    sind = np.where(s==1)[0][1:]
    for i in range(len(sind) - 1):
        s1 = sind[i]
        e1 = sind[i+1]
        subfhr = np.where(fhr[s1:e1] > 0, 1, 0).sum()

        if (subfhr < minseq):

            fhr[s1:e1] = 0
    return fhr

def update(fhr, minseq):
    # convert the sequence to boolean
    nonzero = fhr.astype(bool)
    # stack the boolean array with lagged copies of itself
    seqs = np.stack([nonzero[i:-minseq+i] for i in range(minseq)],
                    axis=1)
    # find the spots where the sequence is long enough
    inseq = np.r_[np.zeros(minseq, np.bool), seqs.sum(axis=1) == minseq]
    # the start and end of the series is are assumed to be included in result
    inseq[minseq] = True
    inseq[-1] = True
    
    # make sure that the full sequence is included. 
    # There may be a way to vectorize this further
    for ind in np.where(inseq)[0]:
        inseq[ind-minseq:ind] = True
    # Apply the inseq array as a mask
    return inseq * fhr


fhr = np.array([1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 8, 3, 0, 8, 2, 4, 7, 0,0,4,1])
minseq = 4 

print(np.all(orig(fhr, minseq) == update(fhr, minseq)))
# True
```